# Which is the right way of doing Siddhasana?

Tags: yoga

In this [video](https://youtu.be/cjIKVwg_v7U?t=148) Sadhguru speaks about Siddhasana and says "there is a point 
on the left heel that today medical sciences are calling it as the Achilles" and after some time he says "you put your Achilles to what is called as muladhara or the perineum in your body".

Now see the image human foot anatomy.

[image]
[image]

All these days I was putting heel bone(calcaneus) to perineum for doing siddhasana. But here Sadhguru says Achilles. Which is the right thing?

Is he calling the hell itself Achilles tendon?

Or the image is wrong?(this less probable as there re many images in google showing the anatomy this way)

Or does Achilles tendon extends till the middle of the heel? As its called calcaneal tendon and the heel bone is called calcaneus.

Or is the Achilles exactly present at the place where its marked in the image? if so how do you put it to perineum? And this also contradicts Sadhguru as he says "there is point on left heel"

**Note: As yoga is not so popular in fitness stack exchange community, I have also asked the same question in Quora: https://qr.ae/TUhmRz**

Comment: To be clear - The *spiritualism* of yoga is not really on topic here, as we are not equipped to address that. The physical aspects (Such as your question) are perfectly on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what Sadhguru is calling the "Achilles" is merely the point on the heel where the Achilles tendon fastens.

From a [wisdom article](https://isha.sadhguru.org/us/en/wisdom/article/why-sadhguru-sit-particular-way) on his website (Which echoes what you posted from the audio):

> I do not sit like this all the time – only when I speak. There is something called Siddhasana. There are many aspects to it. One simple aspect is, **there is a point on the left heel that today the medical sciences are calling “Achilles”**. You heard of the man?
>
> You put your Achilles to your Muladhara, or the perineum in your body. If these two things touch, many aspects are cleared out in you.

(Emphasis mine)

So basically he is saying the same thing as others in a different way, put your heel where the Achilles tendon fastens to your perineum.

Comment: Just to be clear when you say "where the Achilles tendon fastens", that would be some where near Retro Calcaneal Bursa is marked rather than where the heel bone is marked in the second image. So which should be joined with perineum?